# vlc player trouble in Toggle Normal/Repeat/Loop

Tags: vlc-media-player, key-binding

An elderly person uses VLC player to play videos. He wants to Toggle the "Normal/Repeat/Loop". I told him for that the key "l" (small L) is given by vlc.

Now the problem he faces is: how exactly should be press the key "l" to toggle these 3 options?

How fast should press the key in succession? The OSD (on screen display) button for this is so small that he cannot use it. He gets frustrated when he cannot easily repeat or stop repeating a video. Is there a way to set 3 different keys to "Normal/Repeat/Loop", so that it becomes easier to toggle without having to rely on OSD for feedback?
I tried telling him about the command-line option but that's not what I think he wants.
I guess, this applies to vlc on both Windows and Linux. So updated the question.

Comment: The fact that the no loop and loop all look exactly alike except that one is highlighted means that they EXACTLY exactly alike if you have the a bad color theme, like I apparently did on my laptop. Thanks to your question/self-answer, I was able to fix the problem by changing my color theme.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered this question in 8 years and 9 months.

They created a three-position toggle button but, don't tell anybody which button icon means what.

Everything I've found explains push the button once to repeat the current video, twice to loop thru all the videos in the current directory and push it a third time to turn off looping.

My observation is
The button in question is the 2nd from the right on the advanced controls (Toggle the Advanced Controls on or off using the "View" menu).  It looks like two lines with curved arrow heads one on top of the other.
If the button is not highlighted - it is in the NO LOOP setting
If it is highlighted it is the LOOP CURRENT VID setting (Note these button states, look EXACTLY the same except one is highlighted the other is not).
If you see a vertical line between the two horizontal lines on the button, then it is in the LOOP ALL sate. (This one has never worked for me; it does the same thing as the other highlighted choice - ie; loops the current video)

Note: This button will stay in whichever state it is in when you close VLC, hence all the people who said push once for this and again for that and a third time for this were really not much help.  I figured this out myself because none of the sources I could find would explain the different visual states of the "Loop Icon" Even the VideoLan Wiki